# The difference between big.matrix and file backed.big.matrix in R's bigmemory?

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I need to create a large file of 0's and 1's (approx 500K rows and 20K columns) for which I used the bigmemory package in R.

Now as this is new to me, and I have not managed to quite find the answer to my query yet.

---

```
big1 = big.matrix(nrow=nrow(mm),ncol=nrow(cod),init=0,type="char",dimnames = list(as.character(mm$id),cod$coding),backingfile = "big1.bin", descriptorfile = "big1.desc")

is.filebacked(big1) #TRUE

big2 = filebacked.big.matrix(nrow=nrow(mm),ncol=nrow(cod),init=0,type="char",dimnames = list(as.character(mm$id),cod$coding),backingfile = "big2.bin", descriptorfile = "big2.desc")

## presently the for loop step takes about 2 hours
for (i in 1:nrow(big1)){
    big1[i, match(some_columns)] = 1
  }
}

## eventually writing out the big.matrix to file using write.big.matrix also takes about 2 hours.
```

sessionInfo
R version 3.3.0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux 6.9

What is the difference between these two? I would like to know what the difference is when assigning 1's to some cells in either big1 or big2? Are these saved in the backing and descriptor files when initialled in both cases? Or does one have to do something else?

I had saved the session's .RData (using big1 without backing & descriptor  filesin the first instance) and then when trying to load it into R it caused a fatal error and terminated the session. So I would like to know what I could do more efficiently here to load the .RData, rather than having to waste a few hours each time to redo everything.

Many Thanks.

Comment: if you have many more 0 values than 1 values you could also consider using a sparse matrix representation (e.g. see the `Matrix` package)

Comment: @BenBolker: Indeed it has more 0 values, and that was what I tried to use initially. However, I was stuck when trying to convert it to a dense matrixeither within R or from its save output. As I need the 0's and 1's in a dense format text file to be used subsequently as an input in another progeam.

Comment: it's not completely trivial, but I would say that the best solution in the long run would be to work with the data in a sparse format, and write a function (probably in C++/Rcpp for speed) to write the result to a dense format text file ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can either use `big.matrix` or `filebacked.big.matrix`. See the first lines of the function `big.matrix`:

```
if (!is.null(backingfile)) {
        if (!shared) 
            warning("All filebacked objects are shared.")
        return(filebacked.big.matrix(nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, 
            type = type, init = init, dimnames = dimnames, separated = separated, 
            backingfile = backingfile, backingpath = backingpath, 
            descriptorfile = descriptorfile, binarydescriptor = binarydescriptor))
    }
```

So, if you provide an argument `backingfile`, `filebacked.big.matrix` will be called.

Secondly, as standard R matrices, big matrices are stored column-wise and should be accessed column-wise if you care about efficiency. Something like this:

```
big1[, some_column_indices] <- 1
```

Thirdly, for the last part of your question, you can't store a `big.matrix` object because it is an external pointer to a C++ object and when you load it back in memory, this pointer is null and it makes your session crash. You need to use descriptors (for example, when using parallelism). There are least 3 questions on SO which are about this question.

Hope I answered your interrogations.

Comment: Prive´: Thank you it does help.

Though, for the part of assigning 1's, the column indices change for each row hence the big1[i, some_column_indices] ... unless you imply something else? Perhaps, trying to use the foreach function? 

Also, to go with parts 1 and 2, when assigning 1's does the backing/descriptor file change to incorporate that? For example when the descriptor is used to load into a new R session... This is what I also asked as it was unclear to me.

Comment: Anyway, try to access the big matrix columwn-wise if you want it to be fast. For the descriptor, it is only useful to reattach the big matrix to the R session (remapping the file and recreating the big matrix object if you prefer).